# What JOIN would be equivalent to this query?

Tags: sql, filemaker

I have three tables, the relevant structure looking like the following:

```
Routes
| ID |

Runs
| ID | RouteID |

Stops
| ID | RunID | Code | Timestamp |
```

I’m working on a portion of an application that needs to find the next run given a first run. I’ve got a SQL query that’s doing the job, but it’s turning out to be very slow, even though all of the fields being searched are indexed. It looks like this:

```
SELECT   "RunID"
FROM     "Stops"
WHERE    "Code" = 'ABC'
  AND    "RunID" IN ('101', '202', '303')
  AND    "Timestamp" > '2017-02-07 12:34:56'
ORDER BY "Timestamp" ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Note that this is the just form the query is generally taking. The primary keys are actually UUIDs and obviously the tables are more complicated than shown above. But the idea is that I want to find the `Stops` that have a given code, one of a subset of `RunID`s, and a timestamp after a given timestamp.

I’m wondering if the `IN` clause is causing the speed issue. All the above fields within the `Stops` table are indexed, so I would expect this to be a rather quick search, but it’s taking a few seconds each time, and this is within a loop, so this query is making the entire routine very slow.

So, is perhaps a `JOIN` is the answer? The last piece that leads me to this question is all the runs in the `IN` clause’s list have the same parent route. So I’m really searching for all the stops that have a given code and are after a given timestamp *and* have a parent run whose parent route is a given ID.

But, I’m honestly weak with SQL joins. I keep studying them, but I’ve never really gotten them to click for me. Is a join possibly the answer? And if so, how would I write it?

Comment: Are you sure this query is taking too long or the whole process(the loop, retrieving the runId's of a rout and this query)?

Comment: When I step through lines of code within the loop, the only ones that aren't evaluated immediately are those involving this query. All my testing indicates that this query is taking more time than the rest of the loop combined. Because all the search fields are indexed, I would expect results nearly instantaneously (as other queries operate), but this one takes a few seconds each time, which adds up in the loop.

Comment: how many records you have in `stop` table? how many times the loop is being executed?

Comment: The `Stop` table has about 50,000 records. The loop is executed no more than 11 times, but the query could be executed 0, 1 or 2 times within each loop. I haven't had a stopwatch for the execution, but the query takes about 2-3 seconds, so a max of 22 executions at 3 seconds is about a minute long for the routine.

Comment: Note that the above times are when the routine is executed locally. Offloading the execution to the server does speed things up, but only by a factor of 2. My goal is to have execution take on the order of 1 second. Perhaps that's unrealistic with the current algorithm, and I'll need to use a cache of some sort.